# Use Ajax To filter posts?

Tags: wp-query, ajax

Right now I'm submitting a drop-down form to it's own page (action="") to filter posts displayed.

I'd like to not have to refresh the page, which resets the forms. Is there a way to query posts/filter them using ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with @Vinicius' answer with the following changes:

1. Change `type: 'GET'` to `type: 'POST'`
2. Change `ajax: 1` to `action: 'filter_posts'`
3. Replace `add_action('init', 'check_ajax');` with:

   add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'check_ajax');
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'check_ajax');
4. Remove:

   if (!isset($_POST['ajax']))
               return false;

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you'd have to work on it a little bit. Assume you're sending the following variables via jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: location.href,
    data: {
        ajax: 1,
        category_id: <some_id>
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('.posts').html(data);
    }
});
```

Then, you would verify the request like:

```
add_action('init', 'check_ajax');
function check_ajax() {

    if (!isset($_POST['ajax']))
        return false;

    $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=' . intval($_POST['category']) );
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="<?php post_class(); ?>">
            <h2> ... <?php the_title(); ?> ... </h2>
            ... your post template
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    exit();

}
```

It's far from complete and it's not tested, but I hope it gives you some direction. =D

Comment: the URL: location.href, should that be set to /wp-admin/ajax.php? I've been scouring tutorials to try and understand ajax in wordpress but can't seem to figure it out.

And is there more code involved than this? I'm pretty clueless right now

Comment: You're probably getting how ajax work on the admin interface. If you need ajax in your theme, then you have to catch the request in your theme. Take my code and @kalengi's observations.

Comment: I did. Sorry guys, I'm a little newbier than this when it comes to ajax.

I put the first code in a document.ready(function... in a JS file. Then I put the next code in my functions.php. IS this the general idea? I even set up a brand new test template to try this out. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to load the filtered page without AJAX ?

If you are modifying the main query using new WP_Query, you can use this kind of request parameter

`http://wordpress-site.com/page-slug/?query-parameter-1=1&query-parameter-2=2`

where the query-parameter can be taxonomy term, author or any other parameter.

For the JavaScript (JQuery), you can simply use

```
$('#target-div').load(targetPage + ' #target-div-content', function() {
    // do script here
});
```

where targetPage is the request parameter.

Hope this help